# Design support library Tablayout Sliding abnormal

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I'm learning to use Tablayout,but I found that the Tablayout can not slide normal.The tab slides with my gesture.The question is that
When I stop gesture, it will stop immediately, and does not automatically slide to the next tab.

[image: Just like this,it will stop between two tabs]

the layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The code:

```
    SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

Comment: which lib  version are you using

Comment: Where are you calling `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));` as outline in the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html ?

Comment: Need more code about this.

Comment: The lib version is 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: @SebastianRoth he doesn't need to do that as he already called `    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: You should post your ViewPager adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had this happen to me, it was because either 1) My adapter didn't properly create a fragment for that page, or 2) The fragment didn't properly create a view for the page.

Use a tool like Android Device Monitor to check the view on the viewpager and see if it is there as you expect, and that it is not zero width.